# html drop-down menu doesn't work bootstrap

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I've downloaded some template for Bootsrap. It works well on the main page but if I go to another page the drop-down menu doesn't work at all. When I click on it, nothing happens. Also size of all navbar changes on another pages, distance between buttons changes.
Can't get what's the problem. Why does behavior change on another page?

template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span
                class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-lg-4">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Главная</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Покупки</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Bce товары</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Категория 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Категория 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Категория 3</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Категория 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">
                    <i class="bi-cart-fill me-1"></i>
                    Корзина
                    <span class="badge bg-dark text-white ms-1 rounded-pill">0</span>
                </button>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/users/login">Войти</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/users">Регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: var(--bs-nav-link-padding-y) var(--bs-nav-link-padding-x);
    font-size: var(--bs-nav-link-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--bs-nav-link-font-weight);
    color: var(--bs-nav-link-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
.li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I am backender so I don't know properly how it works. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @MoshFeu no errors

Comment: How the navigation works? Is your website a single page application? You can notice if during navigation there is full reload the page or not

Comment: @MoshFeu yes, it reloads full page

Comment: I can't see a reason then. Unless bootstrap doesn't load in the other pages. Can you make sure that bootstrap script appears in the other pages as well?

Comment: @MoshFeu I guess yes, it does. Because links of these scripts are in header.html which is loaded in every template

Comment: @MoshFeu maybe I should send you link of my git repo? Could you please take a glance of my code?

Comment: If you have a public url it would be easier. If I'll need the source code, I'll ask you to update the question

Comment: @MoshFeu no, I dont have a public url :(

Comment: Ok. Even though it's not the typical way of how things are working here, I'll try to help. Please visit my prifile for my contact details.

Comment: @MoshFeu I can't write you a message for some reasons via Twitter (failed to send message). Maybe we can start a chat here?

Comment: I'm not here very often. Please try other channels (also this a holidays week so my availability will be limited)

Comment: @MoshFeu but how can I contact you? you have closed messages on linkedin

Comment: Odd. People are sending messages to me all the time.

Comment: @MoshFeu I've sent you a request on linkedin